# Getting rid of SeekBar progress indicator

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

I' using SeekBar to select values from a range.

[image: SeekBar]

And I'd like to remove the progress indicator (the blue filling before thumb) as the values it is used to select are not actually progress.

I tried settings `android:progress`in the `layer-list` for `android:progressDrawable` but that removes also the background range indicator (gray in the picture above).

[image: SeekBar with custom drawable]

On the other hand if I set only `android:background` It does not look like the platform version's default SeekBar.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `android:progress` item to `android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"`

eg:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</item>
```

Comment: But that still removes the background.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with this `progressDrawable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</item>
```

Comment: On Android 4.0 it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/669143/Screenshot_2015-03-17-18-47-00.png)

Comment: Because it is only a color now, you should set it to a drawable with the right sizes. I've no clue what the original drawable is.